# Why (int)((0.1+0.7)*10) = 7?

Tags: php, floating-point

I came across an interesting fact, but do not quite understand why this is so:

```
$result = (int)((0.1+0.7)*10);
echo $result; // print 7
```

Why 7, not 8?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php See the big red box.

Comment: @bwoebi make that an answer.

Comment: Jeez..... not again.... can't people at least come up with new and original examples when asking this question for the gazillionth time?

Comment: @karthikr too short, and there's already a dupe

Comment: Thanks to all, was inattentive.